# GPSFix doesn't match Rosbag MessageInstance type

Tags: ros, rosbag, gpsd-client, gps-common, gps-umd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using `Diamondback`. I have a captured bag file with data from a number of sensors. I am iterating over the bag file, and initiating a callback function depending on the topic I iterate over in the bag file. However somehow /fix topic is not matching to the message type anytime. Here is a code snippet -

```
BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view){
  if (m.isType<...>()){ ... }
  else if (m.isType<...>()){ ... }
  else if (m.isType<>(gps_common::GPSFix)){     //this never matches!
    ROS_INFO("inside GPS");   
  }    
}
```

My includes are -

```
#include "sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/NavSatStatus.h"
#include "gps_common/GPSFix.h"
#include "gps_common/GPSStatus.h"
```

When I echo the message type:

`ROS_INFO("messageInstance: Topic: %s ", m.getDataType().c_str());`

I can see -

```
[ INFO] [1302536886.734404934]: messageInstance: Topic: gps_common/GPSFix 
[ INFO] [1302536886.819590013]: messageInstance: Topic: gps_common/GPSFix 
[ INFO] [1302536886.826344633]: messageInstance: Topic: gps_common/GPSFix
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9696/gpsfix-doesn%27t-match-rosbag-messageinstance-type/) by [Vaibhav Bajpai](https://answers.ros.org/users/412/vaibhav-bajpai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

switching back to `cturtle` solved my problem.

---

Originally posted by [Vaibhav Bajpai](https://answers.ros.org/users/412/vaibhav-bajpai/) with karma: 58 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0